# In Vim, how to make the position in the changelist local to the buffer instead of the window?

Tags: vim

In Vim, I'm often using `g,` and `g;` to traverse the changelist, but I have noticed that the current position inside the latter changes when I edit 2 buffers in the same window.

For example, if I start Vim with a minimum of initializations, to edit 2 existing files:

```
vim -Nu NORC file1 file2
```

Then make sure that I'm at the end of the changelist in both of them, by typing:

```
99g,
:next
99g,
C-^
```

Finally, if I move at the beginning of the changelist in `file1` (`99g;`), and go back to `file2` (`C-^`), I'm no longer at the end of the changelist but at the beginning. It seems the current position in the changelist of `file1` has been copied to the changelist of `file2`, which I've checked by executing the `:changes` command, and looking at the prefix `>`.

Since the lines contained in the changelist are local to a buffer, I expected the position in the changelist to also be local to a buffer.

For the moment, I'm experimenting these 2 autocmds:

```
augroup my_changelist
    au!
    au BufWinLeave * call s:get_change_position()
    au BufWinEnter * call s:restore_change_position()
augroup END

fu! s:get_change_position() abort
    let changelist = split(execute('changes'), "\n")
    let b:my_change_position = {
                             \   'idx': index(changelist, matchstr(changelist, '^>.*')),
                             \   'view': winsaveview(),
                             \ }
    if b:my_change_position.idx == -1
        let b:my_change_position.idx = 100
    endif
endfu

fu! s:restore_change_position() abort
    if exists('b:my_change_position.idx') && exists('b:my_change_position.view')
        sil! exe 'norm! 99g;'. (b:my_change_position.idx - 1) .'g,'
        call winrestview(b:my_change_position.view)
    endif
endfu
```

I haven't tested them very long, so I don't know if they are reliable.

Is there an option to enable which would make the position in the changelist local to the buffer instead of the window? Otherwise, can the autocmds be improved to be more reliable?

Comment: I'm not aware of such option, unfortunately. Use your autocmds for a while, and fix any issues you see. I don't think someone else can top such first-hand experience from you. If this proves to be really helpful to you, please turn it into a plugin / post it on GitHub to share with others.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Thank you very much for your comment. I'll see how it works and try to fix what I can.